# Cannot submit a report - SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Recently our `SonarQube` instance started rejecting report submissions. Below is the log entry in the access log.

```
192.168.23.XXX - - [07/Dec/2015:16:34:53 +1100] "POST 
/api/computation/submit_report?projectKey=XXX.Sonar.Test HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "SonarQube 5.1"
```

Can anyone help as to how I would diagnose the issue here, the sonar.log is empty of errors. Am I missing a log location?

Here is the exeception on the client:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http://sonar.XXX.com.au:9000/api /computation/submit_report?projectKey=Quantium.Sonar.Test]: <html><body><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>If you are the  administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file to find out what went wrong.</body></html>
        at org.sonar.batch.report.PublishReportJob.uploadMultiPartReport(PublishReportJob.java:131)
        at org.sonar.batch.report.PublishReportJob.execute(PublishReportJob.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:188)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:134)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Server failed to receive the report. You should have a look at server logs (logs/sonar.log).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server did actually receive the post, however it responded with a HTTP 500:

> 2015.12.07 17:03:55 ERROR web[rails] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Mon Dec 07 17:03:55 +1100 2015   Status: 500 Internal Server Error   No such file
>   or directory -
>   C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Temp
>       org/jruby/RubyFile.java:842:in `stat'
>       jar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:33:in`
>   tmpdir'
>       org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
>       jar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:30:in`
>   tmpdir'
>       jar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:109:in
>   `tmpdir'
>       jar:file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:141:in`
>   create'
>       org/jruby/ext/tempfile/Tempfile.java:88:in `initialize'
>       org/jruby/RubyIO.java:852:in`new'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/utils.rb:559:in
>   `parse_multipart'
>       org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in`loop'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/utils.rb:537:in
>   `parse_multipart'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/request.rb:268:in`
>   parse_multipart'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/request.rb:146:in
>   `POST'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in`call'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in
>   `call'
>       file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in`
>   context'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in
>   `call'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in`
>   call'
>       D:/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in
>   `call'
>       file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in`
>   serve_rails'
>       file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in
>   `call'
>       file:/D:/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in`call'

Seems that the TEMPDIR required by JRuby must be set in the wrapper.conf file - it doesn't read env. var:

set.TMPDIR={Path to tmp dir}

I hope this helps anyone else with this issue

Answer (score 0):

In wrapper.conf, add:

```
set.TMPDIR=path/to/dir
```